# MVVM WCF Entity as Model... How to implement propertychange notification in the view model when using Entity as your model

Tags: wcf, binding, mvvm

I am implementing an MVVM Pattern using Entity as my model...  When I instantiate the Model in the setter I add a propertychanged handler to the object to capture the field changes within the entity object...

When I step through code I find that after I modify the field within the object it is firing the Property Change event multiple times...
It has led me to believe that I have done something wrong...

I want to use the entity as my model as I do not want to recreate the object as an abstacted object...

Can any find any fault in the code base below that would cause the SelectedCompany.PropertyChanged to fire more then once when the datagrid field is modified...

I was expecting that that the property changed event would only fire once and am a bit perplexed as to why it fires multiple times...

Was it wrong to add the propertyChange event in the Setter...

Here is the ViewModel...

```
public class CompanyMaintenanceVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private ServiceHandler _serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
private bool _ignorePropertyChange = false; //by default we will execute on every property change...

public CompanyMaintenanceVM()
{
    _companyList = new ObservableCollection<Company>(_serviceHandler.GetCompanies().ToList());
    _selectedCompany = _companyList.First();
    UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(Update) { IsEnabled = true };
    SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(Search) { IsEnabled = true };

    _companyTypeList = new ObservableCollection<CompanyType>(_serviceHandler.GetCompanyTypes().ToList());
}

private string _selectedKey;
public string SelectedKey
{
    get { return _selectedKey; }
    set 
    {
        if (_selectedKey != value)
        {
            _selectedKey = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedKey");
        }
    }
}


private Company _selectedCompany = new Company();
public Company SelectedCompany
{
    get { return _selectedCompany; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedCompany != value)
        {
            _selectedCompany = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCompany");
            SelectedCompany.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(SelectedCompany_PropertyChanged);
        }
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Company> _companyList;
public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyList
{ 
    get { return _companyList; } 
    set 
    { 
        _companyList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CompanyList");
    }

}

private ObservableCollection<CompanyType> _companyTypeList;
public ObservableCollection<CompanyType> CompanyTypeList
{
    get { return _companyTypeList; }
    set { _companyTypeList = value; }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "SelectedKey":
            if (_ignorePropertyChange == false)
            {
                SelectedKeyChanged();
            }
            _ignorePropertyChange = false;
            break;
        case "SelectedCompany":
            _ignorePropertyChange = true;
            SelectedKey = SelectedCompany.CompanyID;

            break;
    }  
}

void SelectedCompany_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //
}
#endregion

private void SelectedKeyChanged()
{
    var companies = _serviceHandler.GetCompanyByID(SelectedKey);
    if (companies.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
        CompanyList = new ObservableCollection<Company>(companies);
        SelectedCompany = CompanyList.First();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Company Record Exsists Matching CompanyID " + _selectedKey);
    }
}

private ICommand _updateCommand;
public ICommand UpdateCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_updateCommand == null)
            _updateCommand = new Updater();
        return _updateCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        _updateCommand = value;
    }
}

private class Updater : ICommand
{
    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void Execute(Object parameter)
    {

    }
    #endregion
}

private void Update()
{
    _serviceHandler.UpdateRepository(SelectedCompany);
    _serviceHandler.CommitRepository();

}


private ICommand _searchCommand;
public ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_searchCommand == null)
            _searchCommand = new Searcher();
        return _searchCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        _searchCommand = value;
    }
}
private class Searcher : ICommand
{
    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void Execute(Object parameter)
    {

    }
    #endregion
}

private void Search()
{



}


}
```

Here is the XAML...

```
<Window x:Class="XERP.Client.WPF.CompanyMaintenance.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Company Maintenance" Height="800" Width="600">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>

        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="422*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="156*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="422*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Text="Company Maintenance Form"
                   FontSize="13"
                   Margin="130,3,129,5"></TextBlock>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2,2,370,2" Width="180">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" >
                <MenuItem Header="_New" Command="New">
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" 
                          IsCheckable="True"
                           Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Click="SaveMenuItem_Click">
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="Close">
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                <MenuItem Header="_Cut" Command="Cut">
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="Copy">
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Paste" Command="Paste">
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Tools" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Actions" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
        </Menu>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="4" Background="Yellow"/>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyList}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CompanyID, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TabItem Header="Detail">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="46"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="657*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="165*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="246*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Button Width="100" Height="20" Margin="10"
                                Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">Company...</Button>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Margin=" 10"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedKey, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8">Name:</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8">Description:</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8">Type:</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" Width="200"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedCompany.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 />
                        <TextBox 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" Width="200"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedCompany.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                />
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Margin="5"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CompanyTypeList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Type"  
                                SelectedValuePath="CompanyTypeID"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedCompany.CompanyTypeID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="23" Name="ghost" Width="0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>


            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="List" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyList}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

                        >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompanyID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                Header="ID" Width="auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                                Header="Name" Width="Auto"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                                Header="Description" Width="Auto"/>
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto"
                                SelectedValueBinding ="{Binding CompanyTypeID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Type"  
                                SelectedValuePath="CompanyTypeID">
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CompanyTypeList, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CompanyTypeList, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="ghost2" Width="0" />
                </Grid>   
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Interesting I removed the twoway binding on the ListView and now the Property change for the selectedcompany is only occurring twice...

Comment: It feels like for every two way binding you have it will trip the ViewModels Property Change event.  Am I on the right track here???

Comment: I think it is really important to understand the properties of Binding...  Because the ListView is just a selector of the current record and no edits can be done it should not be twoway bound...  You should only twoway bind when edits will be done as the textbox and the datagrid require the two-way binding as they will allow for edits of the property from the view and will need to be notified when one is changed so the other can be update apropriately with the change

Answer (score 0):

be aware of using selecteditem with twoway binding AND IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" - maybe there you get your roundtrips.

and what your cause for the following?

```
if (_selectedCompany != value)
    {
        _selectedCompany = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCompany");
        SelectedCompany.PropertyChanged += new    PropertyChangedEventHandler(SelectedCompany_PropertyChanged); //<-- whats that?
    }
```

and why you do this?

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));


switch (propertyName)//why you do this?
{
    case "SelectedKey":
        if (_ignorePropertyChange == false)
        {
            SelectedKeyChanged();
        }
        _ignorePropertyChange = false;
        break;
    case "SelectedCompany":
        _ignorePropertyChange = true;
        SelectedKey = SelectedCompany.CompanyID;

        break;
}  
}
```

Comment: Good point with the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = True... I have since removed that as that is better suited for CollectionViewSource...  The SelectedCompany.PropertyChange Event declaration is to allot me property change handling for the collection what would you suggest?

Comment: I opted to use a seperate property for the SelectedKey rather then binding it directly to the equivalent Selected Property...

Comment: As to allow the bound textbox to be modified and then when it is modified it would then trigger a search for the specific record it was modified to...